# Looking for an example of a certain bivariate function

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I thought about this problem, but I have difficulties in imagining examples or proving that they do not exists.

Is it possible to find a continuous function $f(x,y) : [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that for any $y_1,y_2 \in [0,1]$, we have that there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0,y_1) \not= f(x_0,y_2)$ and   there exists $y_3$ such that $f(x,y_3) = \max(f(x,y_1), f(x,y_2))$, $0 \le x \le 1$?

UPDATE

As pointed out in a comment by @Henry a possible example is $f(x,y) = \frac{x+y}{2}$, so now I would ask for an example with at least some of the above $y_1,y_2,y_3$ such that $y_3 \not= y_1$ and $y_3 \not= y_2$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking for.  $f(x,y)=\frac13$ seems to work.  Or take any $f$ and let $y_3=y_1 \boldsymbol 1_{[f(x,y_1) \ge f(x,y_2)]}+y_2 \boldsymbol 1_{[f(x,y_1) \lt f(x,y_2)]}$ using indicator functions.

Comment: @Henry thank you, I forgot to add a requirement that $f(x,y_1) \not = f(x,y_2)$. I have updated the question.

Comment: With your edit, you seem to have made continuous $f(x,y)$ strictly monotonic in $y$.  My second suggestion will still work but gets simpler, as one of $y_3=\max(y_1,y_2)$ or $y_3=\min(y_1,y_2)$ will work.  For example with $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{2}$ you can have $y_3=\max(y_1,y_2)$.